# Выполнить анимацию вращения шестеренки svg

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

```js
<script>
  c.onclick = e => document.querySelector('svg').classList.toggle('ani');
</script>
```

```css
  .ani  path{
    transform-origin: 19px 19px;
    transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  }
svg { width: 100px }
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <rect style="fill:#ff0000" width="13" height="9" x="19" y="5"></rect>
  <text x="20.2" y="11.7" style="fill: white;letter-spacing: .5px;font-size: 7px;">HD</text>
</svg
```

Каким образом возможно выполнить так, чтобы иконка не скакала и сделать чтобы данная анимация была плавной в обе стороны.

Comment: Задать transition, видимо

Comment: По прежнему прыгает, еще более.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Привет Дмитрий. Объясни более подробно, что значит - "не скакала" Поворот нужен на 30 град или полный оборот?

Comment: Если нужен плавный поворот, то задайте свойство `transition-duration: 1s`. Продолжительность можно задать любую.

Comment: @Laukhin Andrey  TC нужно плавное вращение вперед-назад. На мой взгляд лучше использовать `animation`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT В коде у ТС метод toggle(), поэтому я склоняюсь к простому duration, т.е. шестеренка двухпозиционная

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шестеренка "скачет" потому что неверно указан центр вращения  `transform-origin: 19px 19px;`

Нужно `transform-origin: 18px 18px;`

### Нахождение центра вращения

```
<script>
let  bb = path.getBBox();
console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2)
</script>
```

```js
 c.onclick = e => document.querySelector('svg').classList.toggle('ani');
let  bb = path.getBBox();
console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2)
```

```css
.ani  path{
    transform-origin: 18px 18px;
    transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  }
svg { width: 100px }
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path id="path" d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <rect style="fill:#ff0000" width="13" height="9" x="19" y="5"></rect>
  <text x="20.2" y="11.7" style="fill: white;letter-spacing: .5px;font-size: 7px;">HD</text>
</svg>
```

### Равномерное вращение вперед-назад

Чтобы получить равномерное вращение шестеренки, то необходимо применить `animation` и `@keyFrames`

```js
 c.onclick = e => document.querySelector('svg').classList.toggle('ani');
let  bb = path.getBBox();
console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2)
```

```css
.ani  path{
    transform-origin: 18px 18px;
    animation:rotate 1s forwards linear;
  }
  @keyFrames rotate {
  0% {transform:rotate(180deg);}
  50% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(180deg);}
  }
svg { width: 100px }
```

```html
<div id='c'>КЛИК</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path id="path" d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <rect style="fill:#ff0000" width="13" height="9" x="19" y="5"></rect>
  <text x="20.2" y="11.7" style="fill: white;letter-spacing: .5px;font-size: 7px;">HD</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Под «скачет» вероятно имеется в виду мгновенное изменение угла, duration напрашивается

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Наверное, и если приглядеться, то центр вращения скачет, так как неверно определен

Comment: Да, про центр вращения увидел. А если ТС желает при первом нажатии вращение в одну сторону, а при повторном, в обратную? Но это можно только догадываться.

Answer (score 2):

Для полноты картины, приведу решение для частного случая, если нужна двухпозиционная плавная анимация: при нажатии, вращение в одну сторону, при повторном нажатии, в обратную.

Чистый `transition`, без использования `animation` и `@keyframes`:

```js
c.onclick = e => document.querySelector('svg').classList.toggle('ani');
```

```css
path {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: 18px 18px;
}

.ani path {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">КЛИК</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path id="path" d="m 23.94,18.78 c .03,-0.25 .05,-0.51 .05,-0.78 0,-0.27 -0.02,-0.52 -0.05,-0.78 l 1.68,-1.32 c .15,-0.12 .19,-0.33 .09,-0.51 l -1.6,-2.76 c -0.09,-0.17 -0.31,-0.24 -0.48,-0.17 l -1.99,.8 c -0.41,-0.32 -0.86,-0.58 -1.35,-0.78 l -0.30,-2.12 c -0.02,-0.19 -0.19,-0.33 -0.39,-0.33 l -3.2,0 c -0.2,0 -0.36,.14 -0.39,.33 l -0.30,2.12 c -0.48,.2 -0.93,.47 -1.35,.78 l -1.99,-0.8 c -0.18,-0.07 -0.39,0 -0.48,.17 l -1.6,2.76 c -0.10,.17 -0.05,.39 .09,.51 l 1.68,1.32 c -0.03,.25 -0.05,.52 -0.05,.78 0,.26 .02,.52 .05,.78 l -1.68,1.32 c -0.15,.12 -0.19,.33 -0.09,.51 l 1.6,2.76 c .09,.17 .31,.24 .48,.17 l 1.99,-0.8 c .41,.32 .86,.58 1.35,.78 l .30,2.12 c .02,.19 .19,.33 .39,.33 l 3.2,0 c .2,0 .36,-0.14 .39,-0.33 l .30,-2.12 c .48,-0.2 .93,-0.47 1.35,-0.78 l 1.99,.8 c .18,.07 .39,0 .48,-0.17 l 1.6,-2.76 c .09,-0.17 .05,-0.39 -0.09,-0.51 l -1.68,-1.32 0,0 z m -5.94,2.01 c -1.54,0 -2.8,-1.25 -2.8,-2.8 0,-1.54 1.25,-2.8 2.8,-2.8 1.54,0 2.8,1.25 2.8,2.8 0,1.54 -1.25,2.8 -2.8,2.8 l 0,0 z" style="fill: #141414;"></path>
  <rect style="fill:#ff0000" width="13" height="9" x="19" y="5"></rect>
  <text x="20.2" y="11.7" style="fill: white;letter-spacing: .5px;font-size: 7px;">HD</text>
</svg>
```